# How to send nginx logs to ELK in JSON format?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logstash, elastic-stack

There is a log form nginx:

```
log_format apatsev escape=json
  '{'
    '"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent",'
    '"bytes_sent":"$bytes_sent",'
    '"request_length":"$request_length",'
    '"server_port":"$server_port",'
    '"status":"$status",'
  '}';
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name service-dev.mycompany.io;
    access_log syslog:server=10.233.60.114:5140 apatsev;
```

With ngrep (tcpdump) see:

```
U 10.2.53.165:38051 -> 10.233.60.114:5140 #18
  <190>Mar 19 10:40:07 dev-int-load-balancer2 nginx: {"body_bytes_sent":"81","bytes_sent":"257","request_length":"520","server_port":"80","status":"200",}
```

logstash.conf:

```
input {
  syslog {
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        port => 5140
        type => "log"
        }
  }

filter {
grok {
   match => [ "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"]
   overwrite => [ "message" ]
}
geoip {
   source => "clientip"
}

mutate {
   convert => ["response", "integer"]
   convert => ["bytes", "integer"]
   convert => ["responsetime", "float"]
}

date {
   match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}

useragent {
   source => "agent"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "apatsev-nginx-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

If send is not JSON, ELK responsive field.

If you send JSON, all JSON is inside the message field.

At least how to delete a row

```
<< < 190 > Mar 19 10: 40: 07 dev-int-load-balancer 2 nginx:
```

before JSON ?

Comment: Here is a full example which does not use JSON, I would prefer that as it is more compact. But you could also use json parser in logstash. BTW another option is to use logfiles and filebeat, that’s a bit more robust. https://rzetterberg.github.io/nginx-elk-logging.html